# Downloads folder not working

Tags: directory, downloads

When I go to Files and click on Downloads it says "Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again." in bold and says "Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/kian/Downloads': No such file or directory" in a smaller font. so now I don't have a Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to a terminal window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
mkdir Downloads
```

You can close the terminal window right after that.

That should create the Downloads folder.